# Maintain state of collapsible row on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to maintain whether a row in the table has been expanded or collapsed on refresh of the page.  I am using PHP and Jquery right now to expand and collapse on the click of an image.  Here is my html code.

```
<td style=".$style."><img src='images/triangle-right.png' width='15px' height='15px' id='treeview_".$counts."' name='".$row[0]."'class='treeview' />&nbsp".$row[0]."</td>
```

And here is the jquery to collapse and expand on click

```
$(function() {
    $('.treeview').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var id2 = id.split('_');
        var num = id2[1];
        var row = $(this).attr('name');
        if($('#subrow_'+num).is(':visible'))
        {
            $('#treeview_'+num).attr('src', 'images/triangle-right.png');
            $('#subrow_'+num).hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#treeview_'+num).attr('src', 'images/triangle-down.png');
            $('#subrow_'+num).show();
        } 
    });
})
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Answer (score 0):

You could [set/unset an url variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) whenever the user expand/shrinks a row, something like:

> [www.blablabla.com/list?expandedRow=3](http://www.blablabla.com/list?expandedRow=3)

then on the onReady event of javascript you could check if that variable is defined and show the expanded row like:

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let expandedRow = searchParams.get('expandedRow');
if(expandedRow){
    $('#subrow_'+expandedRow).show();
}
```